# Boolean value is not supported in SQLDelight

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to save a boolean value in SQLDelight but when I run the app, I get this error from an import boolean: "Unresolved reference: Boolean". how can I fix it?
I use SQLDelight = 2.0.0

This is my shared module gradle:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.serializationPlugin)
    alias(libs.plugins.sqlDelightPlugin)
}

kotlin {
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm()

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.coroutines)
//            implementation(libs.ktor.server.core)
//            implementation(libs.ktor.server.tests)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
            implementation(libs.ktor.serialization)
            implementation(libs.dateTime)
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.sqlDelight.android.driver)
        }
        iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.sqlDelight.native.driver)
        }
    }
}
sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("AppDatabase") {
            packageName.set("org.sn.spacexkmp.shared.cache")
        }
    }
}
android {
    namespace = "org.sn.spacexkmp.shared"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
    }
}
```

And this is my Query sq file:

```
CREATE TABLE Launch (
    flightNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
    missionName TEXT NOT NULL,
    details TEXT,
    launchSuccess INTEGER AS Boolean DEFAULT NULL,
    launchDateUTC TEXT NOT NULL,
    patchUrlSmall TEXT,
    patchUrlLarge TEXT,
    articleUrl TEXT
);

insertLaunch:
INSERT INTO Launch(flightNumber, missionName, details, launchSuccess, launchDateUTC, patchUrlSmall, patchUrlLarge, articleUrl)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

removeAllLaunches:
DELETE FROM Launch;

selectAllLaunchesInfo:
SELECT * FROM Launch;
```

If i change this value   `launchSuccess INTEGER AS Boolean DEFAULT NULL,` to INTEGER for example, the error is fixed

Comment: @DPR try my solution below

Answer (score 1):

We don't have NULL value in Integer type, Instead of NULL use 0 as default value.

https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/1.5.4/js_sqlite/types/

```
CREATE TABLE Launch (
    flightNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
    missionName TEXT NOT NULL,
    details TEXT,
    launchSuccess INTEGER AS Boolean DEFAULT 0,
    launchDateUTC TEXT NOT NULL,
    patchUrlSmall TEXT,
    patchUrlLarge TEXT,
    articleUrl TEXT
);
```

Comment: Not working.  The error comes from generated DatabaseQueries and Generated DataModel class by SQLDelight

Comment: Try to use Sqlite, It's easy and wonderfull

Comment: @Murtaza does it support multiple platform?

Comment: @neo Yes it support all the platform.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have NULL value in Integer type, Instead of NULL use 0 as default value.

https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/1.5.4/js_sqlite/types/

And add `import kotlin.Boolean;` in sq file, then rebuild. i'm using version 2.0.1

```
import kotlin.Boolean;

CREATE TABLE Launch (
    flightNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
    missionName TEXT NOT NULL,
    details TEXT,
    launchSuccess INTEGER AS Boolean DEFAULT 0,
    launchDateUTC TEXT NOT NULL,
    patchUrlSmall TEXT,
    patchUrlLarge TEXT,
    articleUrl TEXT
);
```